# Get MySQL event scheduler ON or OFF with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've a script which creates some event in the database I'm configuring this script is basically a part of an auto configuration system for the time tracking software I'm building.

This is the code part where I create all the events and populate 1 table with some data.

```
if(count($error) == 0){
        $timeNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $dbConnect -> exec("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON");

        $createTask1 = "CREATE DEFINER= '".$dbUser."'@`%` EVENT `searchTerm Table Clean` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '".$timeNow."' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO TRUNCATE TABLE searchterm";
        $dbConnect -> exec($createTask1);

        $createTask2 = "CREATE DEFINER= '".$dbUser."'@`%` EVENT `EmptyData` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '".$timeNow."' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO TRUNCATE TABLE tempdb";
        $dbConnect -> exec($createTask2);

        $addUroles = "INSERT INTO `userroles` (`urId`, `userRole`) VALUES(1, 'Admin'),(2, 'Manager'),(3, 'User')";
        $dbConnect -> exec($addUroles);
}
```

As you see I turn the event scheduler `ON` but I want to check the status first then turn it on. Below is what I tried to do,

```
$eveStatus = $dbConnect -> query("SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler'");
$eveStatus -> execute();
$getStatus = $eveStatus -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $getStatus;
```

In the above code I tried to assign the out put to a variable which eventually gave me this error,

> Notice: Array to string conversion

Then I tried this,

```
$eveStatus = $dbConnect -> exec("SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler'");

echo $eveStatus;
```

Which only showed me `0` whether the status was `OFF` or `ON`.

I did search google and SO for an answer but didn't see one which I could use or work with.

Can some one please help me with this.

**I want to detect the if the event scheduler `ON` or `OFF` and then use it to decide to set the status to `ON` if it's `OFF` using a `PHP` `if` condition.**

Comment: What is your exact question? How to check if the `GLOBAL event_scheduler` is set to `ON` ?

Comment: Yes I just want to check if it's on or off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if the `global event_scheduler` variable is ON or not, simply query:

```
select @@event_scheduler
```

The double at signs indicate a global variable

To put this value into a variable in PHP just do this:

```
$eveStatus = $dbConnect -> query("SELECT @@event_scheduler");
$eveStatus -> execute();
$getStatus = $eveStatus -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $getStatus["@@event_scheduler"];
```

Comment: Yes it shows if it's on or off but how do I get it bound to a variable so I can use in a `if` statement.

Comment: @Sand Simple. if you want it in a variable, you do whatever you do with any other value you query from a database. I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: Ah I did that but I was missing array name `@@event_scheduler` stupid of me. Thank you very much m8.

Comment: The notice that you got `Notice: Array to string conversion` was simply warning you that your row returned is an array. (Even if you query just for 1 column.) `fetch_assoc` makes you return an associative array, so you can use the field name as the array index. You could still use your own query, that one should work as well. `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler'` ... The thing is only that then the field name you want will be inside `$getStatus["Value"]`

Comment: Thank you didn't know that part again thank you for taking some time to answer and teaching me.